# How to enable CORS at Spring Security level in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

> I am working with a spring boot application which uses Spring
>   Security. I have tried @CrossOrigin to enable cors but it didn't work.

If you want to find my error refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919460/no-access-control-allow-origin-in-angular-with-spring-boot/48921394#48921394)

[Spring Blogs](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) says that when we are working with **spring security**, we must **enable cors at spring security level**.

And my project is below.

Can anyone explain where should I put those configuration and how to find the spring security level.

Comment: what i have tried can be seen from above link to my previous stack question.

Comment: Gamage   and i have already answered  this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067871/spring-crossorigin-does-not-work-with-delete-method/44069343#44069343 for further ref this https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: **Problem solved.**  check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919460/no-access-control-allow-origin-in-angular-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is a way to make Spring Security 4.1 support CROS with Spring BOOT 1.5

```
  @Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
           .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
}
```

with

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ImmutableList here?

Comment: I have found the solution for this and inserted it in my previous post. I'm not allowed to answer to this question. thank you both @henchiri and Sibin cms because it is combined of your answers. +1 for both

Answer (score 5):

**CORS with Spring Security**:

To enable CORS support through Spring security, configure CorsConfigurationSource bean and use HttpSecurity.cors() configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
            //other config
    }
 
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() 
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

**Reference**, https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-cors-configuration/

Comment: @LahiruGamage it doesn't matter, it's a Spring bean like any others, so as long as it's within a (sub)package relative to the main class, it will work.

Comment: I have found the solution for this and inserted it in my previous post. I'm not allowed to answer to this question. thank you both henchiri and @Sibin because it is combined of your answers. +1 for both

Comment: What to put at the dots in `http.cors().and()...`?