# java rest call get url net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I am writing a rest call as below

```
authenticationService(username: string, password: string) {
    debugger;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('username', username);
    params = params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/basicauth?`,{params},
      ).pipe(map((res) => {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
      }));
  }
```

And from spring boot end I am using @RequestParams like below

```
@GetMapping(path = "/basicauth")
    public AuthenticationBean helloWorldBean(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,@RequestParam(name = "password") String password) {
        String status = authenticationService.isUserAuthenticated(username, password);
             return new AuthenticationBean("You are not authenticated");
    }
```

I am getting the error like

[![this
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA7v9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA7v9.png)

PLease help me on this. Thanks:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS at Spring Security level in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926480/how-to-enable-cors-at-spring-security-level-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I don't think so this issue is related to CORS.

Comment: @Codelover, try to add @CrossOrigin(origins = "host://url_of_your_frontend_server:port") to your controller.

Comment: @NikitaLebed  @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200") I have already added.

Comment: @Codelover post your cross origin configured file too and from your comments your are missing protocol (http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in proxy options provided by the Angular dev server. Refer [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) for more information.

Create proxy.config.json in src folder and add the below contents:

**src/proxy.config.json**

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Then in the AuthenticationService file, modify your HTTP call as below:

```
this.http.get<any>('/api/v1/basicauth', { params }).subscribe();
```

Now run your Angular app with the following flags:

```
ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json
```

**ALTERNATE APPROACH**

**angular.json**

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.config.json"
    },
...
```

Now you can as usual with `ng serve` command without the --proxy-config flag.

**Note**

1. Now you can call any endpoint exposed by your localhost:8080 server without the hostname as shown above and it will work. But note that this will only work in the Dev setup/workflow.
2. In higher environments like Production, you have to host your Angular application from the same domain as that of the backend server to avoid the CORS errors. But note that this is not the only available option to overcome CORS error.
3. As observed from your code snippet, you don't need to add the '?' at the end of the URL as it is automatically generated by the HttpClient if you set the params object.

Hope this helps... Cheers and happy coding!!!

Comment: why do we need to go for `ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.config.json` can we compile with only with `ng-servle`

Comment: @Codelover --proxy-config flag informs angular cli to include the proxy settings. There are 2 ways to inform the CLI about the proxy settings. One way is to specify it using the flags while running the ng serve command or you can specify them in angular.json file. I have edited my answer to include the alternative appraoch.